# Search a word within a <div> and put text inside a tag <p> </ p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how can I be adding a tag

for example, the word "John" in my div.

I am using jquery selector contains my problem to give this one. Append it. 
Follows the code of my page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Beta style</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>John Resig</div>
    <div>George Martin</div>
    <div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
    <div>J. Ohn</div>

    <script>
        $("div:contains('John')")*.append("<p></p>")*
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to wrap the whole text node in a `<p>` tag or just the word "John"?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use jquery's [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) function to accomplish your task,

```
$('div:contains("John")').wrapInner('<p></p>');
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RHxAD/), [demo-1](http://jsfiddle.net/RHxAD/1/)